# Show proper message to user

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on this login views. And i want the user to be notified if he/she doesn't enter his/her credentials. For example if username is not entered then i need to show something like "Please enter your username" and also for password.
And also for both username and password. This my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender {

if (![self.usernameBox.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.passwordBox.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self showLoginProcess:true];
    [[AuthSingleton getInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AuthSingleton getInstance] attemptLoginWithUsername:self.usernameBox.text andPassword:self.passwordBox.text];
} else
{
    NSLog(@"username or password is empty %@", kBaseURL);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what i understand is that  you are finding some logic to display proper message with proper condition. Try this may be it will help.

```
if ([self.usernameBox.text length] > 0 && [self.usernameBox.text length] > 0)
{
    [self showLoginProcess:true];
    [[AuthSingleton getInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AuthSingleton getInstance] attemptLoginWithUsername:self.usernameBox.text andPassword:self.passwordBox.text];
} else
  {
    NSString *message;
    if ([self.usernameBox.text length] <= 0 && [self.passwordBox.text length] <=0) 
           message = @"Enter both the Fields";
     else if ([self.usernameBox.text length] <= 0 ) 
          message = @"Enter username";
     else if ([self.passwordBox.text length] <=0 ) 
           message = @"Enter password";

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: `nil` is not equal to `@""`. So you need to check for the text's length instead. Like `[self.usernameBox.text length] > 0`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. There is also something called alertview right? To alert the user. Im sorry im new to programming. I have a lot to learn

Comment: @Shruti. Stupid question. How do i accept an answer? Sorry im new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Abdelilah Near my answer where you can upvote the answer there will be an tick mark in grey colour. click on that it will turn green. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it by single if condition,

```
if ([self.txtUName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtUName.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""] ||[self.txtPassword.text isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"UserName or Password is empty" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```